# SolrNet Autofac - Use SolrPostConnection

Tags: c#, autofac, solrnet

I'm using `SolrNet` with `Autofac` DI in my web application like this:

```
var solrNetModule = new SolrNetModule(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["solr"].ConnectionString);
solrNetModule.HttpWebRequestFactory = new BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory("****", "****");
builder.RegisterModule(solrNetModule);
```

My queries are quite long and sometimes end up with a 404 in Jetty, I'm pretty sure this happens because the length of the URL.

I've been reading about the [`SolrPostConnection`](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Impl/SolrPostConnection.cs) and that sounds like a proper solution to my problem, but I'm having trouble implementing it in my `Autofac` setup.

I know the `Autofac` `SolrNetModule` integration internally uses

```
builder.RegisterInstance(solrConnectionInstance).As<ISolrConnection>();
```

But I can't figure out how to override it or `.Register` `Autofac` to use the `SolrPostConnection` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to override registration for interface `ISolrConnection`. The main problem is that `SolrNetModule` doesn't provide mapping of SolrConnection to itself. Try out the example below. I added another registration of `SolrConnection` to make it available for injecting to contructor of `PostSolrConnection` without dependency loops

```
[Test]
public void SolrRegistrationOverride()
{
    // Arrange
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var serverUrl = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["solr"].ConnectionString;
    var httpWebRequestFactory = new BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory("****", "****");
    var solrNetModule = new SolrNetModule(serverUrl);
    solrNetModule.HttpWebRequestFactory = httpWebRequestFactory;
    builder.RegisterModule(solrNetModule);

    builder.RegisterType<SolrConnection>().AsSelf()
           .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("serverURL", serverUrl))
           .WithProperty("HttpWebRequestFactory", httpWebRequestFactory).AsSelf()
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<PostSolrConnection>().As<ISolrConnection>()
           .WithParameters(new Parameter[]
           {
               new ResolvedParameter((prm, сtx) => prm.Name == "conn", (prm, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<SolrConnection>()),
               new NamedParameter("serverUrl", serverUrl)
           });

    var container = builder.Build();

    // Act
    var conn = container.Resolve<ISolrConnection>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<PostSolrConnection>(conn);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Happy to help=)

Comment: It seems like this won't work when using WebRequestFactory. The PostSolrConnection doesn't use the Factory to create WebRequests but uses WebRequest.Create instead (which is incorrect if you'd ask me). In my case Authorization doesn't work.

Comment: I see. In this case you would probably need to add your own implementation of `PostSolrConnection`, that will receive factory in its constructor too. `PostSolrConnection` doesn't look to complex to do it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Might create a Pull Request later. Thank you for your help.